# What version of pyinstaller should I be using with Python 3.11.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am writing a software package on an Arch Linux platform using Python 3.11.3.  In addition, I am also using poetry to manage my dependencies, and have run into a problem.  When I try to install pyinstaller with the command `poetry add pyinstaller` I get the following error.

```
The current project's Python requirement (>=3.11,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - pyinstaller requires Python <3.12,>=3.7, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.12,<4.0

Because no versions of pyinstaller match >5.12.0,<6.0.0
 and pyinstaller (5.12.0) requires Python <3.12,>=3.7, pyinstaller is forbidden.
So, because todo-six depends on pyinstaller (^5.12.0), version solving failed.

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For pyinstaller, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.11,<3.12"
```

This implies that the most up to date version of pyinstaller does not work with Python 3.11.3.  The dependencies using in my `pyproject.toml` file are shown below.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
pyqt6 = "^6.5.0"
pandas = "^2.0.2"
pyinstall = "^0.1.4"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.3.1"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
mypy = "^1.3.0"
black = "^23.3.0"
isort = "^5.12.0"
flake8-bandit = "^4.1.1"
flake8-bugbear = "^23.5.9"
flake8-builtins = "^2.1.0"
flake8-comprehensions = "^3.12.0"
flake8-implicit-str-concat = "^0.4.0"
flake8-print = "^5.0.0"
tox = "^4.5.2"
pytest-cov = "^4.1.0"
pyupgrade = "^3.4.0"
pre-commit = "^3.3.2"
```

Based on the fact that for some reason I can not install the most up to date version with poetry, I walked my way through every version of pyinstaller until one of them installed, which was version 4.5.1, with the command `poetry add pyinstaller==4.5.1`.  However, when I run the command `pyinstaller  -F -w- i icon.ico --add-data "todo_six:todo_six" todo.py I get the following error, which indicates that pyinstaller version 4.5.1 is not compatible., or at least that is what I think it means.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
             ^^^^^
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 107, in run
    parser = generate_parser()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 78, in generate_parser
    import PyInstaller.building.build_main
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 35, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.depend import bindepend
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.depend import dylib, utils
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.depend import bytecode
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bytecode.py", line 95, in <module>
    _call_function_bytecode = bytecode_regex(rb"""
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bytecode.py", line 60, in bytecode_regex
    pattern = re.sub(
              ^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/re/__init__.py", line 185, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bytecode.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    lambda m: _instruction_to_regex(m[1].decode()),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jonwebb/Desktop/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bytecode.py", line 40, in _instruction_to_regex
    return re.escape(bytes([dis.opmap[x]]))
                            ~~~~~~~~~^^^
KeyError: 'CALL_FUNCTION'
```

If someone could help me understand what these errors mean, and how to get pyinstaller working with my current dependencies, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What happens if you do as suggested by the error message and add a python dependency into the toml file i.e. ```python ">=3.11,<3.12"```

Comment: I completely missed that.  That did seem to fix one problem, but only revealed another that I will post in another question.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such problem. Replaced poetry with virtualenv and everything worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).